# Min-Max Normalization using AWK

Tags: bash, shell, awk, text-processing, gawk

I dont know Why I am unable to loop through all the records. currently it goes for last record and prints the normalization for it.

## Normalization formula:

New_Value = (value - min[i]) / (max[i] - min[i])

## Program

```
{
    for(i = 1; i <= NF; i++)
    {
        if (min[i]==""){  min[i]=$i;}     #initialise min
        if (max[i]==""){  max[i]=$i;}     #initialise max
        if ($i<min[i]) {  min[i]=$i;}     #new min
        if ($i>max[i]) {  max[i]=$i;}     #new max
    }

}
END {
    for(j = 1; j <= NF; j++)
        {
        normalized_value[j] = ($j - min[j])/(max[j] - min[j]);
        print $j, normalized_value[j];
    }
}
```

## Dataset

```
4 14 24 34
3 13 23 33 
1 11 21 31
2 12 22 32
5 15 25 35
```

## Current Output

```
5 1
15 1
25 1
35 1
```

## Required Output

```
0.75 0.75 0.75 0.75
0.50 0.50 0.50 0.50 
0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00
0.25 0.25 0.25 0.25
1.00 1.00 1.00 1.00
```

Comment: `$j` in the `END` block will be value of the `j`'th field of the last record in the dataset.

Comment: Firstly, I don't understand your required output. Where are these numbers coming from? Min of what? Max of what? Secondly, you are referencing NF in your END clause, which really doesn't make sense.

Comment: I am really new to awk bit and having a hard time understanding the awk language, sorry for that. The min and max are calculated from the dataset i have shown, I calculated min and max of each field(col.) and then finally normalizing each field using min-max algorithm.

Comment: min[i] is never == ""   it defaults to 0 at the point you ask

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would process the file **twice**, once to determine the minima/maxima, once to calculate the normalized values:

```
awk '
    NR==1 {
        for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) {
            min[i]=$i
            max[i]=$i
        }
        next
    }
    NR==FNR {
        for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) {
            if      ($i < min[i]) {min[i]=$i}
            else if ($i > max[i]) {max[i]=$i}
        }
        next
    }
    {
        for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) printf "%.2f%s", ($i-min[i])/(max[i]-min[i]), FS
        print ""
    }
' file file
# ^^^^ ^^^^  same file twice!
```

outputs

```
0.75 0.75 0.75 0.75 
0.50 0.50 0.50 0.50 
0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 
0.25 0.25 0.25 0.25 
1.00 1.00 1.00 1.00
```

Comment: Thanks, I understood finally.

Comment: can you have a look at my another ques. on awk. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37897154/one-nearest-neighbor-using-awk?noredirect=1#comment63248037_37897154  need help with it

Comment: This is very useful. My input data contains header and also a first column with ids. How can I do to include this info in my output using this script?

Comment: Assuming the header is the first line, add `FNR == 1 {next}` as the first line of the awk code. For the first column, consider how you have to adapt the for loops.

Comment: I am using this script suggested to normalize my data, but I got this error message: awk: cmd. line:17: (FILENAME=input.txt FNR=1) fatal: division by zero attempted. How to solve it?

Comment: Did you adjust the `NR==1` condition if you have a header row?

Comment: I removed the header. This error happens because I have one column with only 0 values.

Answer (score 0):

The given answer uses same file to be loaded twice, this can be avoided with following modified script:

```
# initialization on min, max and value array to be used later
NR == 1 {
    for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) {
        value[i] = $i
        min[i] = $i
        max[i] = $i
    }
}
# finding min and max for each column
NR > 1 {
    for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) {
        value[((NR-1)*NF)+i] = $i
        if      ($i < min[i])    {min[i] = $i}
        else if ($i > max[i])    {max[i] = $i}
    }
}
END {
    nrows = NF
    ncolumns = NR
    for (i=0; i<(ncolumns); i++ ) {
        for (j=1; j<(nrows); j++ ) {
            printf "%.2f%s", (value[(i*nrows)+j]-min[j])/(max[j]-min[j]), OFS
        }
        printf "%.2f\n", (value[(i*nrows)+j]-min[j])/(max[j]-min[j])
    }
}
```

Save the above awk script as `norm.awk`. You can run this from shell (and redirect if needed) as:

```
awk -f norm.awk data.txt > norm_output.txt
```

or you can run this `norm.awk` script from vim itself as:

```
:%!awk -f norm.awk
```

Which will replace the existing values with min-max normalized values.